# Digital clock wiget not displaying time in TextViews

Tags: android, widget, textview, clock, simpledateformat

I am very new to java and programming for android.  So far, it has been fun!  I made a digital clock widget that worked, except it did not update the time.  After some research, I have rewritten the code using a different method.  Now, I am not getting the time to show up in my TextView layouts.  Can anybody help me figure out what the issue is?

Here is my entire ClockWidgetProvider.java

```
package com.acsoft.bsiclock;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Service;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.acsoft.bsiclock.R;

/**
 * The ClockWidgetProvider class is the widget place holder for the ClockWidget.
 */
public class ClockWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    /**
     * Inner class representing the update service.
     */
    public static class ClockUpdateService extends Service {
        private static final String ACTION_UPDATE =
            "com.cmwmobile.android.samples.clock.action.UPDATE";

        private final static IntentFilter intentFilter;

        static {
            intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
            intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
            intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_UPDATE);
        }

        /**
         * BroadcastReceiver receiving the updates.
         */
        private final BroadcastReceiver clockChangedReceiver = new
                BroadcastReceiver() {
            /**
             * {@inheritDoc}
             */
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                updateTime(context);
            }
        };

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            registerReceiver(clockChangedReceiver, intentFilter);
        }
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            unregisterReceiver(clockChangedReceiver);
        }
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_UPDATE)) {
                    updateTime(this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method buildUpdate builds the RemoveViews to be displayed.
     * @param context used to retrieve resources.
     * @return RemoveViews instance.
     */

    private static RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(new Date());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.date,currentDate );

        String hour = "hh";
                SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.hour, hour);

        String minute = "mm";
                SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.minute, minute);

        String ampm = "a";
                SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.ampm, ampm);

        return views;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);

        context.stopService(new Intent(context,
            ClockUpdateService.class));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);

        context.startService(new Intent(
            ClockUpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        context.startService(new Intent(
            ClockUpdateService.ACTION_UPDATE));
    }
    /**
     * Method updateTime updates the time.
     * @param context used to retrieve resources.
     */
    private static void updateTime(Context context) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = buildUpdate(context);

        ComponentName clockWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            ClockWidgetProvider.class);

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.
            getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(clockWidget, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

And here is my layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/clockbr"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    tools:context=".Bioshock_Infinite_Clock_4x2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:textColor="#4c4439"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="33dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hour"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".305"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#4c4439"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/minute"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".365"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#4c4439"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/am_pm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".32"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#4c4439"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" /> -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ampm"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".32"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#4c4439"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="serif" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't see any errors is my logcat as fa as I can tell.  I have tried a few different things to the SimpleDateFormat, but still no luck.  Hopefully I am missing something simple!

Any help is appreciated!